# How to add color in assembly OS code in qemu?

Tags: assembly, colors, x86, osdev, bios

I am trying to set red color for text in this code:

```
[bits 16]       ;кажемо коду що юзаєм 16 бітний формат
[org 0x7c00]    ;адрес де біос буде завантажувати бутлоадер

start:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax ;ці три рядки будуть очищувати регістри ax, ds, es
    mov es, ax
    
    mov si, hello;встановити точки індексу джерела для рядка hello
    call print_string; вкликаємо функцію print_string
    
    hello db 'CyberOS terminal edition', 0x04, 'version 0.1a', 0x0A, 'created by SomeOne_GuY',  0 ;вивести на екран
        ; Вызов функции для вывода строки "version 0.1" в красном цвете
     
    
    
;далі будемо описувати функцію тут

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E ;Значення яке оброблює переривання, щоб зробити значення з усіх та вивести на екран
    
.repeat_next_char:

    lodsb ;завантажуємо перший символ з того hello: символ "C"
    cmp al, 0
    je .done_print
    int 0x10    ;переривання відео виклику BIOS
    jmp .repeat_next_char
    
.done_print:
    ret

times (510 -($-$$)) db 0x00 ;ставимо 512 байти. $$ - означають 2 байти, це каже біосу, що це бутлоадер компоненти (завантажувальні компоненти)
dw 0xAA55 ;сиґнатура буту(boot), що каже біосу що тут є бут(boot) компоненти
```

In line

```
    hello db 'CyberOS terminal edition', 0x04, 'version 0.1a', 0x0A, 'created by SomeOne_GuY',  0 ;вивести на екран
```

I use 0x04 color (red color), but I have just next picture and have no red color:
[image]

For starting it I use this command:

> ```
> qemu-system-x86_64 -fda C:\Users\Ukraine\Documents\CyberOS\boot.bin
> ```

The `-fda` flag is used for the visualization of colors

Answer (score 1):

You access display like this:

```
; your video ram address is 0xB8000
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
xor di, di
```

`es:di` characters go every 2 bytes meaning offset 0 and 2 displays characters while offset 1 and 3 displays colors of those characters.

```
mov BYTE es:[di] , ch1
mov BYTE es:[di + 1] , color1
.
.
.
```

Look at [here](https://www.computerhope.com/color.htm) for color codes.

Comment: `0xb8000` doesn't fit in 16 bits: the usual method is to put `0xb800` in a segment register.  Also, x86 addressing modes support `si+1` directly so you can do `mov BYTE [si+1] , color1` instead of wasting an instruction incrementing a register by 1. You can just `add si, 2` between characters. (But `inc si` / `inc si` is more compact). Also, if your `ch1` and `color1` are constants, you'd normally do one 16-bit store.  Or to reuse the same color, you'd load the color into the high 8 of a register (like AH) and load new characters into the low 8 (like AL), and store the full register (like AX).

Comment: @PeterCordes All your points in your comments are welcomed and acceptable. I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

I added some code which just sets color to green of all characters on the screen. Text mode 80x25 has 2000 characters and every odd address is character's attribute.

```
start:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax ;ці три рядки будуть очищувати регістри ax, ds, es
    mov dx,0xb800
    mov es, dx
    mov cx,2000
    mov di,1
    mov al,2
    
    Color:  
       mov es:[di],al
       add di,2
    loop Color    
    
    mov si, hello;встановити точки індексу джерела для рядка hello
    call print_string; вкликаємо функцію print_string
```

Comment: What adress has green color?

Comment: I have no idea. :D

Answer (score 1):

### The issues

> ```
> call print_string
>
> hello db 'CyberOS ... , 0x0A, ...
> ```

You should never allow the execution to fall through in your data. Simply insert some form of endless loop here. And to perform a newline, you need to output both a carriage return (13) and a linefeed (10). See below.

> I use 0x04 color (red color), but i have just this picture and have not red color:

When in a graphics video mode as opposed to a text video mode, the BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh that you are currently using does support specifying the text color in the BL register. If you setup the 16-color 640x480 graphics video mode 18, you'll be able to output in any of the 16 text colors AND you'll gain 5 extra text lines as a bonus (30 rows instead of 25).

### A solution

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

start:
    cld
    xor  ax, ax
    mov  ds, ax
    mov  es, ax

    mov  al, 0x12 ; AH is already 0x00 from the above `xor ax, ax`
    int  0x10     ; BIOS.SetVideoMode 18 (16-color 640x480)
    
    mov  bl, 4    ; Red (text color)
    mov  si, hello
    call print_string

    jmp  $        ; Simplest of the endless loops
    
    hello db 'CyberOS terminal edition version 0.1a', 13, 10, 'created by SomeOne_GuY',  0

; IN (bl,si) OUT (si) MOD (ax)
print_string:
    jmp  .b
.a: mov  ah, 0x0E   ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  0x10
.b: lodsb
    cmp  al, 0
    jne  .a
    ret

times (510 -($-$$)) db 0
dw    0xAA55
```